# Reflexives and use of "se" in "terminarse"

Tags: pronombres, reflexivos, se

I'm slowing working my way through reflexive pronouns, and I understand that there are several uses of the pronoun 'se' :

- **Accidental / unplanned circumstances** (se me cayó el vaso)
- **Passive Voice** for general statements (se habla español)
- **Impersonal** for when the doer of the action is deemphasized (se dice que es bueno)
- **Reciprocal** (nos besamos)
- **Direct Object pronouns** that change from lo,la,los,las to *se* ('la la envió' becomes 'se la envió')

But...

My Venezuelan friend told me that the correct translation of "the game is almost over" is `"casi se termina el partido"`.

I don't understand how the 'se' in this final sentence fits any of the criteria for using 'se.' How is this a reflexive sentence?

Comment: A more accurate translation could be _"El partido está a punto de terminar"_ or _"va a terminar"_. For me, _"Casi se termina el partido"_ looks like an incomplete general statement.

Comment: In your last bullet point I guess you mean: "***Indirect*** Object pronouns that change from ***le, les*** to se (***le*** la envió' becomes 'se la envió'). Direct object pronouns never change to "se".

Answer (score 5):

Carlos Alejo is right, but I wanted to add a few grammatical explanations.

The verb *terminar* can be intransitive ("to finish"), or transitive ("to finish off sth", "to terminate sth"). The verb *terminarse* has the same meanings, plus the sense of "to run out". That means the two sentences below are equivalent:

> El partido está a punto de terminar = El partido está a punto de terminarse.

because the sense of "finishing" is present in both *terminar* and *terminarse*. However, to say "we ran out of cookies" you can only say:

> Las galletas se terminaron

and not ٭*las galletas terminaron* because the sense of "running out" is only present in *terminarse*.

The pronoun *se* in *terminarse* can be analysed in different ways: when it means "to finish" it can be considered an **ethic dative**; when it means "to run out of" it is a **pronominal verb marker** (*marca de verbo pronominal*). Ethic datives don't change the meaning of a verb and can be dropped (that's why the first two sentences are equivalent), while pronominal verbs markers can't be dropped. Sometimes, dropping a pronominal verb marker changes the meaning of a verb, as in *acordar* ("agree to") and *acordarse* ("remember"); and sometimes, dropping it leaves you with a verb that doesn't mean anything, as in *enterarse* ("find out"), whose non-pronominal form, *enterar*, just doesn't exist. [EDIT: *Enterarse* isn't a great example because the non-pronominal form, albeit less common, also exists and it means "to inform". *Dignarse*, *arrepentirse* or *atenerse* are better examples.]

I guess "ethic dative" and "pronominal verb marker" are two cases you have to add to your list.

Comment: Me acabo de _enterar_ que **enterar** no existe. :-) @Yay no entendí esa parte.

Comment: @DGaleano El verbo que estás usando en "me acabo de enterar" no es *enterar* sino *enterarse*. El pronombre puede ponerse al principio o al final de locuciones verbales como "acabar de". La versión sin el pronombre ("acabo de enterar que enterar no existe") no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: @Yay Gracias. Ya entendí. Lo que dices es que en ningún caso se usa _enterar_ sin que antes (o después) haya un pronombre. Creo que en casos como **"Acabo de enterar a Carlos de la situación"** no hay pronombre pero el sujeto "Carlos" cumple la misma función por lo tanto lo que dices aún aplica porque podría escribirse como **"Acabo de enterarlo de la situación"**.

Comment: @DGaleano En ese caso "a Carlos" sería el objeto directo, igual que "informar a Carlos". La verdad tienes razón, no había caído en ese uso de "enterar". Supongo que "dignar(se)" o "arrepentir(se)" habrían sido mejores ejemplos.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the examples you give seem just like particular cases of a wider case: the pronominal verbs. You can read about them in the *Gramática Española*, from [this page](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wurYgfKPXkaQSlUR) onwards.

As you already know, some verbs append the "*se*" suffix: these are the pronominal verbs, but this does not mean that the verb takes part in a reflexive sentence. If you want to know if a verb can be used as a pronominal verb, check the DRAE:

> **[terminar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZYwREwl)**
>
> Del lat. *termināre*.
>
> 3. intr. Dicho de una cosa: **cesar** (‖ interrumpirse o acabarse). U. t. c. prnl.

These letters at the end (*U. t. c. prnl.*) mean *usado también como pronominal*, "also used as a pronominal (verb)". This means that you can either say *el partido está a punto de terminar* or *el partido está a punto de terminarse*.